# conditional formatting is not retained

Tags: excel-formula

I have a conditional formatting rule in place that says "If cell Q4 is blank, format the cells so that all cell's fill, borders, shading, etc. are also blank, so that it appears as if there is no content present, and is formatted accordingly.  This cleans up the look of the report if content has not been added yet. When Q4 is not blank, the conditional formatting rule is not applied, and there is some significant formatting I have done on that range of cells.  See the attached picture for what I hope to be a better explanation of the intended function.  All of the cell formatting is not applied (appears as a blank sheet) if the highlighted cell (Q4) is empty.

My issue is, when I scroll down so that the cells that are affected by the conditional formatting are no longer in view, and then scroll back so that they are in view, the conditional formatting keeping the cells with no border, shading, fill, etc. is not retained for some, but not all, of the cells in the desired range.  What is even more strange is if I click out of excel (into a browser window for example) and then back into excel, one additional cell no longer has the conditional formatting applied that keeps it blank.  If I go into the cell that controls the visibility of the affected cells (Q4) which is already empty, and press delete, the conditional formatting gets applied until I scroll out of view and the process repeats itself.  Any suggestions on correcting this excel bug?  The data is not formatted as a table, so unchecking banded rows is not applicable, and I have made sure that EnableFormatConditionsCalculation is set to TRUE in the VBA, where were the two solutions that I found online to fix this same issue.

[image]

Correctly functioning conditional formatting shown, where because Q4 is not empty, the cell formatting is visible (conditional formatting to make the range of cells appear blank is not applied)

Answer (score 0):

There is some subtle cause for this. Might Q4 have an invisible space character? If it does, you can change the conditional formatting rule to =LEN($Q$4)=0. Also, did you 'anchor' cell $Q$4 within your formatting formula? Did you intend for the blank cell condition to follow your data per row- Q4....Q5...Q6? If so, Q4 should be relative. You do not show your actual conditional formatting formula. It will help greatly to include your formula itself.

Comment: `=LEN($Q$4)=0` as the formula did not work.  My original formula was in the conditional formatting rules manager window in the provided image.  For reference it is `=$Q$4=""`.

Comment: I enlarged your image and I now see that. My mistake.One other possible cause that I can think of: Did you have cell C4 as the active cell when you typed in the conditional formatting formula?  I duplicated your image with random data in my spreadsheet, using both your formula and mine and it produced the desired results.

Comment: Yes I just tried re-doing the rule with C4 as the active cell and I am still experiencing the bug.